# Add text header to existing Java files?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have multiple Java files, now I want to add author name, time and date in every java file. Is there way of updating all java files with such headers in Batch, or any eclipse plugin to do that dynamically?

I tried using eclipse plugin Eclipse Copyright Generator but its giving error as
No repository found at https://dl.bintray.com/jmini/Eclipse-Copyright-Generator/.

can someone help me with this , any help is appreciated

Comment: This isn't something that's provided by Java; I recommend looking into a text manipulation language or tool such as `sed`

Comment: _Search > File..._ can be used to replace text: e.g. use a regular expression (`\A` matches the beginning of the file) and hit _Replace..._ button at the bottom.

Comment: @howlger can you pls help with sample code , if it is possible by code

Comment: The [Eclipse Copyright Generator](https://jmini.github.io/Eclipse-Copyright-Generator) plugin is the easiest and the most flexible way to add headers. You can see how to use it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-copyright-header#code_template).

Comment: This does not help @DevilsHnd giving err such as 
No repository found at https://dl.bintray.com/jmini/Eclipse-Copyright-Generator/.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Eclipse's own Copyright Tool. Check https://wiki.eclipse.org/Development_Resources/How_to_Use_Eclipse_Copyright_Tool, but **use the update site for your hopefully more current version than shown in the installation section**. It was originally meant to sync the dates inside the Copyright comment with the change history in CVS (now, git), but I think it can add the comments regardless.

Comment: could not find http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.12-I-builds/  @nitind

Comment: Assuming you're on the current release, use https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.19 . You should have some version of it already in your known list of update sites.

Comment: Following the description at  https://wiki.eclipse.org/Development_Resources/How_to_Use_Eclipse_Copyright_Tool has worked for me - used update `https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.19` as suggested at the site.
This tool can be used to add comments.

Answer (score -3):

From the main menu bar, navigate to Preferences
Then, navigate to Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates
From the right-hand side of the window, expand the Code section and select New Java files

Then, we go to Edit Template by clicking on the Edit button
In the Edit Template window, we add our copyright license header in the Pattern text area
And, click on the OK button to update the template
Finally, let's click on the Apply button to finish the setup

However, this method has some disadvantages:

We cannot use this to add a copyright header to existing source files
We cannot include custom variables in the license text, like our company name
It's not flexible enough to let us choose different copyright license headers
We can use this only on Java and Javascript source files
Luckily, there is an alternative in the form of the copyright generator plugin.

You can also use copyright  generator plugin
For more understanding :
You can visit the below site for providing headers [eclipse header](https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-copyright-header)

Comment: This is no longer a link-only answer, so thank you for that edit. Unfortunately, it is just a direct copy/paste of the less relevant section of the linked page. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: This does not help @Rishav Raj giving err such as 
No repository found at https://dl.bintray.com/jmini/Eclipse-Copyright-Generator/.